# UserControll and calling TextBox events from this UserControll as primary events

Tags: c#

I have UserControl which has two components

```
public System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox innerComboBox;
public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox innerTextBox;
```

and when i am using this UserControl i can not call Validating event like

```
myName.Validation += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(myName_Validating);
```

becouse not working. I must call it like.

```
myName.innerTextBox.Validating += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(myName_Validating);
```

can i override my UserControll that all events will be calling from innerTextBox of TextBox ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your UserControl, try adding it like this:

```
public new event CancelEventHandler Validating {
  add { innerTextBox.Validating += value; }
  remove { innerTextBox.Validating -= value; }
}
```

Then your `myName.Validating` should work like you want.

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can "wrap" them in some ways, meaning you will need to expose the events from your top-level user control to which outsiders can subscribe, and then, subscribing to the inner-control even handlers, "inform" your top-level subscribers. For instance...

```
public class MyControl
{
    public event CancelEventHandler Validating;

    public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox innerTextBox;

    public MyControl()
    {
        //post-instantiation stuff here

        innerTextBox.Validating += myName_Validating;
    }

    void myName_Validating(oject sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Validating != null) 
        {
            Validating(sender, e);
        }
    }
}
```

How exactly you want to wrap them is up to you; if you want your control to have some handling logic prior to publishing and executing the top-level subscriptions (can be handy in threading situations) then this will work, otherwise a more concise and practical approach for your might be what LarsTech suggests.